# upload only current file with netbeans

Tags: netbeans, file-upload

I'm using netbeans 6.9.1 to work on a php project, how do I manually upload a file without having to 'run' the project?

Comment: PHP project? Java Web App project? Something else?

Comment: I believe it says php project

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under the options->keymap, I mapped Ctrl-L to upload, which is easy enough.

The only other place to upload is to right-click the file in the project browser and 'upload', unlike aptana there's no button for it, which is what got me stumped.

Comment: I find this to be a strange one too. I frequently find that the auto upload times out so have to resort to manually uploading the file, a button up on the toolbar would certainly make things less frustrating.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the project's *"Run Configuration"* properly configured as a *"Remote Web Site (FTP, SFTP)"*, then simply right-click on the file in the *"Projects"* pane and click on *"Upload"* in the file's context menu.

If you want to upload automatically on save instead of on run,

- Right-click on the project node in the *"Projects"* pane (it's the top-most node in the tree)
- Click on *"Properties"* in the project's context menu.
- Click on *"Run Configuration"* in *"Categories"*
- Change *"Upload Files"* to *"On Save"*
- Click *"OK"*

If you sometimes want to upload on run, sometimes on save, sometimes only manually, sometimes to one server, sometimes to another server, or any combination of the run configuration options, then you can click on the *"New..."* button to create and save one or more run configurations. You can then choose which one is active on the run configurations project properties page, or set it through *"Set Configuration..."* on the project's context menu.

Comment: I save alot, and not always when the file is ready for uploading, so the auto-upload would break the site while im working on it :(